# How Do we extract only the DATE portion from datetime datatype column in Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

For Ex: I am bringing the Hive table column (datetime data type) value in Pig and want to extract on;y the DATE portion. I have tried using ToDate function. the below is the Error Information. Please help me in this critical situation.

The Original Value in this column is "2014-07-29T06:01:33.705-04:00", I need out put as "2014-07-29"

```
ToDate(eff_end_ts,'YYYY-MM-DD') AS Delta_Column;
```

> 2016-07-28 07:07:25,298 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt
>   - ERROR 1045:  Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.ToDate as multiple or none of them
>   fit. Please use an explicit cast.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column name is f1 which has the timestamp with values like 2014-07-29T06:01:33.705-04:00, you will have to use GetYear(),GetMonth,GetDay and CONCAT it to the required format.

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE CONCAT(
                       CONCAT(
                       CONCAT((chararray)GetYear(f1),'-')),
                       (CONCAT((chararray)GetMonth(f1),'-')),
                              (chararray)GetDay(f1)) AS Day;
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the Work around to figure out and Its working by this way:

```
ToDate(ToString(eff_end_ts,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'YYYY-MM-DD') AS (datetime: Delta_Column)
```